# How to get the hash in isValidSignature for ERC1271?

Tags: signature, verify, eip-1271

AFAIK, to verify a message, I need three things - message, signer wallet address and signature which is the signed message. Like when I use [MyEtherWallet signing tool](https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/sign).

But in function [isValidSignature](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IERC1271.sol), there's a hash of bytes32 type.

```
function isValidSignature(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) external view returns (bytes4 magicValue);
```

How do I actually get the hash and what is the algorithm used (MD5, SHA, etc)? I'm actually using this [SignatureChecker library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/SignatureChecker.sol) now but can't see to know how I can generate the hash.